# Data Manipulation using Advanced Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, export-to-excel, data-manipulation

Can someone please help me with the formulae to the below attachments?

[image: Data Manipulaton]

Comment: What is designation? And check out Data Validation - it's on the Data Tab.

Answer (score 2):

## Intro

As @SolarMike pointed out, we do not have enough information for your specific case. Therefore, I give you a general answer, which you can adapt to your needs.

## Definition of lists

[image]

- Create a separate tab (here: *lists*)
- Define your first list (here: *List A*). It comprises the entries that can be selected (here: *mainlist_label*) and the names of each entry's corresponding sublist. Please note, that each blue label indicates a range name I assigned to the used cells below.
- Define the entries for each of your sublists.

## Usage

[image]

### Main list

- Select the range which should be validated against your main list (here: `A2:A10`).
- Go to *Data*/*Data validation* to open the respective dialog (labels can differ).
- Choose *list* in the upper drop down, select the *source* input field. press **F3** and select **mainlist_label** or enter `=mainlist_label`.

### Sub lists

- Select the range which should be validated against your main list (here: `B2:A10`). Note, that `B2`should be the active cell of your selection.
- Go to *Data*/*Data validation* to open the respective dialog (labels can differ).
- Choose *list* in the upper drop down, and copy/paste the following formula into *source*: `=INDIRECT(INDEX(mainlist_sublists,MATCH(A2,mainlist_label,0)))`

### Explanation

- The `MATCH`formula searches the `mainlist_label` range for the content of `A2`.
- The `INDEX`formula provides the corresponding sublist name
- The `INDIRECT`formula tells Excel to provide the range that has been assigned to that name.

Comment: I use this *named ranges* approach as it is quite easy to understand and can easily be adjusted by users that cannot deal with formulas. They only need to know how to create and update named ranges.